# How to add XNamespace (Xml.Linq) to XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement, xnamespace

Hi i need to create some XML Elements like:

`<Example_Property xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="string">ExampleData</Example_Property>`

But my code:

```
            XElement newElement = new XElement("Example_Property");

            XNamespace datatypes = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes";

            newElement.Add(new XAttribute(datatypes + "dt", "string"));

            newElement.Value = "ExampleData";
```

only creates so far:

```
<Example_Property dt:dt="string">ExampleData</Example_Property>
```

How i have to work with the Namespace?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It ouput `<Example_Property p1:dt="string" xmlns:p1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">ExampleData</Example_Property>` for me (by just doing `Console.WriteLine(newElement);`

Comment: My Problem is solved with: XElement newElement = new XElement("Example_Property");

                XNamespace datatypes = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes";
                
                newElement.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xmlns + "dt", datatypes.NamespaceName);

                newElement.Add(new XAttribute(datatypes + "dt", "string"));
                
                newElement.Value = "ExampleData";

Comment: @happycroc consider that you can answer your own question in StackOverflow